# how to split large numbers to groups in R

Tags: r, split, largenumber

I am having troubles to separate large numbers into groups. 
For example:

```
a<-"2009031930111"
```

what I would like to get it:

```
year<-2009
month<-03
day<-19
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why not make it an actual date object? (`strptime(a, "%Y%m%d")`)

Comment: Are you looking for `substr()`?

Comment: Possibly duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11446499/r-programming-multiple-substr ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `substr()` you can do:

```
a<-"2009031930111"
substr(a, 1, 4)
substr(a, 5, 6)
substr(a, 7, 8)
```

eventually you want to convert: `as.numeric(substr(...))`

Comment: Thanks a lot, very helpful :)

Answer (score 3):

As @Ananda Mahto said you can convert it into date object and then using `lubridate` package separate its years, months and date

```
a<-"2009031930111"
x <- strptime(a, "%Y%m%d")
library(lubridate)
year(x)
# [1] 2009
month(x)
# [1] 3
day(x)
# [1] 19
```